# mysql_insert_id() is returning 0

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mysql-insert-id

I've looked through the various answers and none of them seem to be helping. I have a simple Insert Query that is working as expected. Nothing special

```
$user_account_query = mysqli_query($dbc,"
        INSERT INTO ACCOUNT (EMAIL, IS_OPEN)
        VALUES ('$email', 1)")
        or die ('Could not add user: '. mysql_error());
```

It is successfully inserting the record into my db

[image]

I also have an auto-incrementing column in the table being called
[image]

However, when I call

```
$message = mysql_insert_id();
```

I get 0. Does anyone have any advice on how to get the correct ID?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're mixing up mysql and mysqli

```
$message = mysql_insert_id();
```

should be

```
$message = mysqli_insert_id($dbc);
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually you are using myqli Libraray and then you are using other library function mysql_insert_id() you have to use mysqli_insert_id() that is why you getting 0